# Cannot read csv files uploaded using pandas in Djnago

Tags: django, pandas

I have the following view defined in my Django views:-

```
def csv_file_upload(request):
    if request.method == "POST" and request.FILES['file_upload']:
        registry = request.POST.get('reg_select').lower()
        csv_file = request.FILES['file_upload']
        data = pd.read_csv(csv_file, delimiter="\|\|")
        print(data.head())
    return render(request, "csv_file_upload.html", {})
```

But the pd.read_csv part is giving me this error:-

```
cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

The sample csv file that I have is like this:

```
Col_A||Col_B||Col_C
A0||B0||C0
A1||B1||C1
```

The same file I can read using `pd.read_csv()` without using Django and do no get this error.

Why is this error being caused when using Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files are uploaded as bytes and not as string ( expected )

You should read file and decode its content to string

```
csv_bytes = request.FILES['file_upload'].read()
csv_text = csv_bytes.decode('utf-8')
string_buffer =  io.StringIO(csv_text)
data = pd.read_csv(string_buffer , delimiter="\|\|")
```